# Concatenate string with scope variables in template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a case where I want to concatenate a string with scope defined variable like this :

```
$scope.variable1 = "Test Name";
$scope.variable2 = "Test 2 Name";

<a href="#">{{variable1? "({{variable1}})" : variable2}}</a>
```

I want when variable1 is set then display "(variable1)" otherwise "variable2".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
<a href="#">{{variable1? "({{variable1}})" : variable2}}</a>
```

To:

```
<a href="#">{{variable1 ? "(" + variable1 + ")" : variable2}}</a>
```

Comment: You must need to write "Change" and  "To". I thought both ways are correct. ;) Thanks

Comment: @MahaDev, and I thought that [yellow background of the _qoute_](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41259196/1) with your code inside is clear enough ;)

Answer (score 1):

try {{variable1? '('+variable1+')' : variable2}}

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

        <a href="#">{{variable1 ? "(" + variable1 + ")" : variable2}}</a>

    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.variable1 = "Test Name";
            $scope.variable2 = "Test 2 Name";
        });
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There are no brackets involved, please read the question carefully or see other's answers

Comment: Yes because i was already aware about the ternary operator but the problem of concatenation. I didn't did it before. Well i up-voted it again, don't worry.

Comment: Ok. I thought adding a bracket is not a big deal for a developer.

Comment: Yes but i never used concatenation inside "{{ }}" , that's why asked. :)

Comment: Ok. Any angular scope variables written inside {{ }} will be evaluated in the ui by the value in scope.